# GGplot2 How to change outlier shape per boxplot group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to distinguish every boxplot's outliers by shape. For example boxplot 1 uses crosses, boxplot 2 uses circles etc.
I tried to achieve this by doing

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = price)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

and by simply doing

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price, shape=cut)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Both options fail. How can I achieve different outlier shapes for each boxplot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `outlier.shape` argument have to assign them by `NULL` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=cut, y=price, shape = cut)) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NULL)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice solution Quinten. You might want to add `key_glyph = draw_key_point` to `geom_boxplot` to ensure that the different points are shown in the legend.

Comment: That is it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, That is a good point!